# How to append textbox from none-name thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am building a simple server and just wanted to know how do i update a textbox in the main thread from the threads that are handling the server.

Its for and eventlog so want to replace *MessageBox.Show("Server Started");* with a function e.g. *Form1.EventLog("Server Started");* that will append my textbox named *tb_EventLog*.

I have googled it and got something todo with delegate\Invoke and maybe try using BackgroundWorker. But been playing all day and all attemps have failed and caused me compile errors so started fresh.

If someone could place the function in there and comment it so I understand it I would be very thankful.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Botton Pressed");
            Server server = new Server();
            server.Start();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Stop();

        }
    }
}
```

Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    class Server
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;
        private static bool listen;

        public Server()
        {
          this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
          this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            listen = true;
            this.listenThread.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Server Started");
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            listen = false;       
            MessageBox.Show("Server Stopped");
        }

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (listen)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //create a thread to handle communication
                //with connected client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }

            this.tcpListener.Stop();
        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while (listen)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client sends a message
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //a socket error has occured
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //the client has disconnected from the server
                    break;
                }



                //message has successfully been received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
                MessageBox.Show(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello World!");

                clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                clientStream.Flush();
                clientStream.Close();
            }

            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }

  }
```

Also what would be the best way to stop the server thread, have I done it correctly?

Many Thanks

**UPDATED**

Ok I have edited the above code and removed the oThread like was sugguested as it was pointless.

Please help me fix this its sounds simple but its driving me mad :) Im trying to make the server class update a textbox on the main thread.

Thanks Again.

Comment: A side note:  making oThread a static variable on the form seems like a really bad idea... you don't really want to share this thread across every instance of this form

Comment: BFree has solved this for you, and has included sample code... not sure what more you want

Answer (score 1):

You should use events:

```
class Server
{
   public event EventHandler ServerStarted;

   protected virtual void OnServerStarted()
   {
       var handler = this.ServerStarted;
       if(handler != null)
       {
           handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
       }
   }

   public void Start()
   {
        listen = true;
        this.listenThread.Start();
        OnServerStarted();
   }
}
```

Then, in you winforms:

```
    Server server = new Server();
    server.ServerStarted+= (o,ev) => this.Invoke(new Action( () => this.textBox1.Text = "Server Started"));
    oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Start));
    oThread.Start();
```

Comment: @James: No, I have it right. Since start will be called on a different thread, the event will be raised on that thread (not the UI thread) and therefore you need to use invoke in the event handler.

Comment: You're right, my brain is tired, and I'm thinking how I would handle this if the thread was running a method on the form itself, not from an external class

Comment: @James B: Well thanks for trying anyway. Anyone have any ideas or links?

Comment: @BFree: Im reading up on event handler now but im new to c# so dont know where to start :/

Comment: @BFree: Thanks for the example but I need to append the text box in the Server class not in main thread running Form1. How do people make their Event Log Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

For setting the text on a background thread do as BFree has explained. About your code I would suggest the following -

1. I think, your the Thread - `oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Start));` is redundant. In `Server.Start` you are again starting a listener thread. So you should simply call `Server.Start` from your Winform.
2. You are not starting your threads as background threads. If a thread is a foreground thread it will keep you application running as long as the thread is alive. See this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx. You should set the `IsBackground` property to `true` on all thread instances created by your program.
3. For getting better performance either use threads from [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) or [PFX Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) in .Net 4. The threads then will be background threads by default. Moreover your program will not have the overhead of thread creation. Using PFX will help leverage your multi-core processor providing great performance benefits.

read this excellent guide on threading http://www.albahari.com/threading/